# Python entry get returns thread information

Tags: python, multithreading

I've stumbled upon a weird issue.

I have an `Entry()` field, where I get the IP to connect with. If I click the button, I want to get the value from the `Entry()` field.
Now, this was all working fine, until this morning when it started returning the `Thread` info. After some struggling, I found a work around, but I'm sure this isn't the right way to do it.

```
SERVER_IP = "192.168.8.210"

def threaded(f, daemon=False):
    import queue

    def wrapped_f(q, *args, **kwargs):
        '''this function calls the decorated function and puts the 
        result in a queue'''
        ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
        q.put(ret)

    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        '''this is the function returned from the decorator. It fires off
        wrapped_f in a new thread and returns the thread object with
        the result queue attached'''
        q = queue.Queue()

        t = threading.Thread(target=wrapped_f, args=(q,)+args, kwargs=kwargs)
        t.daemon = daemon
        t.start()
        t.result_queue = q        
        return t
return wrap

def __init__(self, parent):
    SERVER_IP = self.config.get('preferences','ip')


def initFriendList(self):
    self.eIp = Entry(self.infoFrame)
    self.eIp.configure(width=16)
    self.eIp.insert(0, SERVER_IP)
    self.eIp.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=(0,10))

    self.btnConnect = Button(self.infoFrame, text="Connect", command=self.connect)
    self.btnConnect.configure(width=8)
    self.btnConnect.grid(row=1,column=1, pady=(0,0), sticky=W)

@threaded
def connect(self):
    global IS_MASTER, IS_CONNECTED, LATENCY, SERVER_IP
    SERVER_IP = self.eIp.get()
    the_ip = self.eIp.get()
    print(SERVER_IP, the_ip)
```

this print returns:

```
<Thread(Thread-3, started 6136)> 192.168.0.170
```

Why do I keep getting this thread info?

Comment: Just `print(the_ip)` instead?

Comment: Yes I do, but I want to know why the `SERVER_IP` returns `<Thread(Thread-3, started 6136)>`

Comment: what is `self.infoFrame`

Comment: The frame containing the `Button` and the `Entry`

Comment: Well that is how you are setting the value so obviously your problem lies there. How are you testing the code? Also why are you using   SERVER_IP = self.eIp.get() and 
    the_ip = self.eIp.get()?

Comment: I'm using `print()` statements between my lines of code to see what value the variable contains